# Trim leading zeros from a number in Dart

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

How can I trim the leading zeros from a string of numbers in Dart?

For example:

- 012345     -> 12345
- 0000122424 -> 122424
- 0101230090 -> 101230090

Answer (score 5):

One way to do it without regex is..

```
String result = int.parse('012345').toString();
```